# getserversideprops data sometimes returns undefined

Tags: javascript, next.js

```js
export default function Id({ data }) {
    return ( 
        <div>
            <Head>
                <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
                <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title>{ data.botData?.username }</title>
                <link rel='icon' href={ `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${data.botData._id}/${data.botData.avatar}.png?size=4096` } />
            </Head>
        </div>
     )
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res, url }) {
    let getBotData = await fetch('...', {
        body: JSON.stringify({
            id: req.url.slice("/bots/".length),
            user_id: id
        }),
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST'
    })

    let botData = await getBotData.json()

    let data = {
        botData: botData.data,
        botInfo: botData.info,
        comments: botData.comments
    }

    return {
        props: {
            data
        }
    }
}
```

there is a 1 out of 3 chance that `data` that is returned from `getServerSideProps` is undefined for some reason, I guess this is because the page was loaded before `getServerSideProps` was done fetching? Because it does take quite some time for my backend to do its stuff and return the data

Comment: "page was loaded before `getServerSideProps` was done fetching" - That wouldn't happen, SSR'd pages wait for `getServerSideProps` output to populate its props. Are you certain your API request is returning the expected response when that issue occurs?

Comment: @juliomalves yes, because it says "can't read property of username of undefined", undefined being the data returned from getServerSideProps

Comment: I'm not saying it's not, I'm asking if `botData` has the expect value returned from the API.